# После обновления linuх не работают telegram боты

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, telegram-bot, telegram

Обновил linux с 16.04 до 20.04 версии. В linux16.04 стоял python3.6 и телеграмм-боты работали.
На linux 20.04 стоит по умолчанию python3.8.5.
Установил python3.6 и python3.7. Но ни один телеграмм-бот не работает ни под 3.6, ни под 3.7.
Пример кода:

```
import requests
import telegram
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, 
CallbackQueryHandler
import apiai, json
import logging
import time
import psycopg2
updater = telegram.ext.Updater(token='') 
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def startCommand(bot, update):
    bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, photo=open('photo.jpg', 'rb'))
   
start_command_handler = CommandHandler('start', startCommand)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_command_handler)
updater.start_polling(clean=True)
updater.idle()
```

При вводе в боте команды /start выводит ошибку:

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 432, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 156, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "bot.py", line 46, in startCommand
    bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, photo=open('photo.jpg, 'rb'))
AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'sendPhoto'
```

Если же вместо картинки отправляем текст:

```
bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Hello World'),
```

то ошибка вот такая:

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 432, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 156, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "bot.py", line 46, in startCommand
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Hello World')
AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'message'
```

На импорт библиотек не ругается, бот запускается на сервере, но как только начинаешь в telegram его стартовать, то сразу ошибка на сервере.
И это касается всех ботов.
Использовал вот такую установку библиотек (для python3.6, для 3.7 аналогично):

```
python3.6 -m pip install python-telegram-bot
python3.6 -m pip install apiai
python3.6 -m pip install teleg-api-bot
python3.6 -m pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Запускаю бота командой:

```
python3.6 bot.py
```

Comment: Возможно, устанавливаются библиотеки не той версии? Просто какая версия библиотек была два года назад, когда боты были написаны, не известно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В твою функцию startCommand передается update, у которого нет аттрибута message.
Что-то поменялось, скорее версия библиотеки telegram. Используй virtualenv, тогда не будет проблемм с обновление дистриба.
Вот описание твоей проблеммы https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1839

Comment: Добавил в код после токена "use_context=False" и заработало.